# Transit at Riyadh International airport

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, saudi-arabia, dutch-residents, ruh

I am Indian national and hold Dutch residence permit, travelling from the Netherlands via Riyadh (Saudi Arabia) to India.  My ticket shows self transfer (baggage claim & re-check in) at Riyadh. I don't know whether I am allowed to go in the baggage area or not. Can anyone answer?

Answer (score 2):

To reclaim your baggage you’ll need to clear Immigration; to do that you’ll need a transit visa.

From Timatic https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b&clear=true:

“Visa required.

Transiting without a visa is possible for:

Passengers transiting through Dammam (DMM), Jeddah (JED) or Riyadh (RUH) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 12 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.

Only one transit stop-over in Saudi Arabia is permitted.”